# Rewriterule .htaccess in subfolder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to perform a rewrite in a subfolder using the .htaccess file. The current url has a form like:

```
domain.com/subfolder/chapter.php?urlkey=name
```

It needs to be rewritten to:

```
domain.com/subfolder/chapter/name
```

In the subfolder I have a .htaccess file with the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /subfolder/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
    RewriteRule ^chapter/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ chapter.php?urlkey=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Modrewrite is enabled, but for some reason when I go to the url

```
domain.com/subfolder/chapter/name
```

It returns the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: urlkey
```

Comment: do you have an htaccess file in parent folder that contains /subfolder/ ?

Comment: I don't have an htaccess file in the parent folder.

Comment: Could you post the full Notice error? It should have a file and line number. If so, post that file please :)

Comment: The full error is     Notice: Undefined index: urlkey in /sites/domain.com/www/subfolder/chapter.php on line 4, this is where php tries to receive the chapter object using the urlkey.

Comment: Can you put `LogLevel debug  rewrite:trace3`
 to your apache configuration file ( not to .htaccess ), restart Apache and then post relevant log entries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have this code in `subfolder/.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/

RewriteRule ^chapter/([\w-]+)/?$ chapter.php?urlkey=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.

Also there is no need to rewrite to `chapter?...` you can rewrite to `chapter.php?...`

Answer (score 1):

Your error is not related to htaccess rules.

Notice: Undefined Index

Happens when you try to access an array by a key that does not exist in the array.

A typical example for an `Undefined Index` notice would be check sample code below.

```
$data = array('foo' => '42', 'bar');
echo $data['spinach'];
echo $data[1];
```

Both `spinach` and `1` do not exist in the array, causing an to be triggered.

The solution is to make sure the index or offset exists prior to accessing that index. This may mean that you need to fix a bug in your program to ensure that those indexes do exist when you expect them to. Or it may mean that you need to test whether the indexes exist using [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists) or [`isset`](http://php.net/isset):

```
$data = array('foo' => '42', 'bar');
if (array_key_exists('spinach', $data)) {
    echo $data['spinach'];
}
else {
    echo 'No key spinach in array';
}
```

If you have code like:

```
<?php echo $_POST['message']; ?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="message">
    ...
```

then `$_POST['message']` will not be set when this page is first loaded and you will get the above error. Only when the form is submitted and this code is run a second time will the array index exist. You typically check for this with:

```
if ($_POST)  ..  // if the $_POST array is not empty
// or
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') ..  // page was requested with POST
```

The notices above appear often when working with $_POST, $_GET or $_SESSION. For $_POST and $_GET you just have to check if the index exists or not before you use them. For $_SESSION you have to make sure you have the session started with session_start() and that the index also exists.

Comment: The name of the chapter is different for all chapters. Shouldn't this be different? Using you're code I receive the same error: Notice: Undefined index: urlkey in /sites/domain.com/www/subfolder/chapter.php on line 4.

Comment: Hmm, I understand what you're saying and that the urlkey is not found is definitely the error. However, it works when the url is written fully, but not when it's rewritten using htaccess. Thus there must be an error in the htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

When removing `RewriteBase` it does working for me

put this in subfolder please check

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^chapter/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ chapter.php?url=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

and you have to add `chapter.php?` instead of `chapter?`.

Comment: Removing the RewriteBase doesn't change anything for me. It gives me the `Undefined index: urlkey` error

Comment: The presence of the `RewriteBase` directive in this instance is entirely optional.